# Alignment in Forest

Tags: forest

- I'm not super comfortable (yet) with `forest`.
- I have a problem with the alignment of nodes.
- Where am I wrong?

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
    box/.style={rounded corners, 
        draw=gray!50, 
        fill=orange!20,
        font=\sffamily,
        minimum height=2em},
    [Actions, box 
        [Common shares, box
            [porte 
                [Droits de vote, box 
                    [donne droit à 
                        [Une voix à l'élection du board, box]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
            [peut donner droit à
                [Dividendes, box,name=div
                    [distribue
                        [Part des profits, box]
                    ]
                    [décidé par,name=decision
                        [Le Board, box, name=dir]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
        [Actions préférentielles, box
            [donne droit à,  name=droit]
        ]
    ]
    \draw (droit)--(div);
\end{forest}
                                    
\end{document}
```

PS: side question on the go... how can I get smaller fonts when not in a `box/.style`?

Comment: Use `for tree={text depth=0.25ex,minimum height=2em}`.

Comment: @user238301 merci unknown user :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To align the texts, add an appropriate `text depth`. To get an alternating pattern of boxed and non-boxed nodes, use the `isodd` function.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
    box/.style={rounded corners, 
        draw=gray!50, 
        fill=orange!20,
        font=\sffamily,
        },
    for tree={text depth=0.25ex,
    if={level==0||isodd(level)==1}{box,minimum height=2em}{minimum height=1.2em}}   
    [Actions
        [Common shares
            [porte 
                [Droits de vote 
                    [donne droit à 
                        [Une voix à l'élection du board]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
            [peut donner droit à
                [Dividendes, name=div
                    [distribue
                        [Part des profits]
                    ]
                    [décidé par,name=decision
                        [Le Board, name=dir]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
        [Actions préférentielles
            [donne droit à,  name=droit]
        ]
    ]
    \draw (droit)--(div);
\end{forest}
                                    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You only need to define anchors of node:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
    box/.style={
        rounded corners,
        draw=gray!50,
        fill=orange!20,
        font=\sffamily,
        minimum height=2em,
        anchor=north    % or center <---- added
        },
    for tree = {
    if level =  2{}{if level = 4{}{box}}
                }
    [Actions
        [Common shares
            [porte
                [Droits de vote
                    [donne droit à
                        [Une voix à l'élection du board]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
            [peut donner droit à
                [Dividendes, name=div
                    [distribue
                        [Part des profits]
                    ]
                    [décidé par, name=decision
                        [Le Board, name=dir]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
        [Actions préférentielles
            [donne droit à,  name=droit]
        ]
    ]
    \draw (droit)--(div);
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:**
To `forest` code is added specification `for tree` which prescribe nodes style depending from level, where they are.

Comment: Eagle eye ! merci :) But do you notice the text in nodes still don't align ?

Comment: @JeT, see edited answer. I added some trick, which defined nodes stlyle according to level in which they are.

Comment: merci Mr Z ! works prefectly.